# What are the historical milestones in image Deconvolution?

Tags: deconvolution

Norbert Wiener came up with the Wiener Deconvolution in 1949 or something like that. But what happened after that? When was Richardson-Lucy deconvolution developed for example? And what happened between that and Adobe's deblur demo in Creative Cloud?